# Where can I define custom keywords for c++ in visual studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

It is explained here for vstudio 2003 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zy61y8b8%28VS.80%29.aspx

But I Can't find for vstudio 2010 to 2013.

Comment: It should also work for VS2010-2013.

Answer (score 0):

I works also for VS2010-2013. But the settings has not changed to "C/C++ User Keywords" in "Tools|Options|Fonts and Colors".

Of course, you must copy the "usertype.dat" in the corresponding VS directory.